How can I fix Android resource linking failed?
When I try to run the code it keeps saying "Android resource linking failed". I tried to rename the file in the AndroidManifest.xml from
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.actions"
            android:resource="@xml/Birthday" />


to lowercase** "/birthday"** but it keeps changing automatically into** "/Birthday".**
COPY OF ERROR MESSAGE
Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\Nahum\AndroidStudioProjects\HappyBirthday\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:24: error: resource xml/Birthday (aka com.example.happybirthday:xml/Birthday) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.
I tried to rename the file I tried to rename the file in the AndroidManifest.xml into lowercase  but it keeps changing automatically to uperrcase.
